# AspNet "Visual studio Code" for Mac, how to add a local DLL dependency in project.json manually or using DNX, DNU?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dnx, dnu

There is third party DLL stored as a normal `something.dll` file (i.e. it is not a part of the repository, and it is not published using the repository) and sample code for this DLL, `Program.cs`. Whole project is simple console app, generated using `yo`.

How to add a dependency to this DLL to `project.json`?

I would like to add the dependency manually to `project.json` with reference to the local file, or I would like to know how to add the file to the local repository (which is stored in `.dnx` folder, I suppose) and then use it in `package.json`.

My `ASP.NET` `Visual Studio Code` installation uses `dnx` and `dnu`.  Thank you in advance.